# get rid of BottomNavigationView "selected" view

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile, bottomnavigationview

When a menu item is pressed it changes its look.
It appears to me like this:
[image]
Do you know a way to get rid of this?
If not, is there a way to change the color?
For example, change the color from black to blue.

BottomNavigationView item:

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bnv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"

            />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

---IndicatorStyle---
1)

```
 <style name="App.Custom.Indicator" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator">
        <item name="android:color">@color/blue</item>  
    </style>
```

2. Add this line to bottomNavigationView xml code :

```
app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/App.Custom.Indicator"
```

**OR**

```
   app:itemRippleColor="@color/green"
    app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@color/green"
```

Makes an "animation" of an explosion.
The color type does not matter.